# Python 2 Dimension Array (Matrix) with string indices

Tags: python, data-structures, dictionary, matrix

In Python (2.7), is there a native 2 dimensional data structure that can be accessed through string based indices?

I know you can have a dictionary that can be accessed with a string index, for example:

```
>>> dic = dict()
>>> dic['grumpy'] = 'cat'
>>> print(dict['grumpy'])
'cat'
```

But what I would like is a data structure that can be accessed like:

```
>>> dic['grumpy']['frumpy'] = 'cat'
>>> print(dict['grumpy']['frumpy'])
'cat'
```

Array seems to be a no-go since it only allows integer based access... any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

nesteddict = defaultdict(dict)

nesteddict['abc']['spam'] = 'ham'
```

Note that what you describe is a simple nested structure; you can also build it without using `defaultdict` but that class makes it all the easier to do so.

Comment: Oh, come on.  That's just not fair.  Promise me that when you hit 100k you'll give the rest of us at least thirty seconds worth of handicap!

Comment: Amazing! thank you sir for the extremely fast response!... I'll accept the answer once the minimum 15 mins have passed. :)

Comment: @ToOsIK: I am in to hurry; perhaps others can think of something that is better still, give them a chance too! :-)

Comment: @DSM: I'll be gone a large part of tomorrow... try and spot the lulls! :-P

Comment: @DSM -- Do you think we could convince the moderators that Martijn has somehow hacked SO so that he gets the chance to see every question before other users -- Or that he's some kind of really smart and useful non-spam-bot?  (Seriously -- I don't think I can even type that quickly)

Comment: @mgilson: Full disclosure: I use a Kinesis Advantage split keyboard and type using a Dvorak layout instead of QWERTY.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- I keep telling myself that I'm going to learn Dvorak -- One of my co-workers switched relatively recently ...

Comment: @MartijnPieters which one makes you more productive? Kinesis Advantage split keyboard or Dvorak layout.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Both. A regular keyboard slows me down slightly, a QWERTY layout would reduce me to a snail pace.